# TypeNotFound: Type not found: (schema, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )

Tags: python, python-2.7, suds

I've read and tried the other solutions I've seen posted, but despite this I can't seem to get this to work. I have the following code:

```
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 
location='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd')
imp.filter.add(['http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/','http://tempuri.org/', 'http://tempuri.org'])  # the schema to import into.
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(url='https://apitest.integrapay.com.au/PayLinkService.svc?singleWsdl', username='user', password='password', doctor=d)
```

And I get the error:

TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(schema, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'

I'm sure it's something simple, thanks for the help, I am using suds 0.4.1.

Comment: I am having an identical problem, even with numerous other soap clients> have tried multiple incarnations with 'Doctors' and the best I have seen is a stack overflow from python.