# suds Type not found: Array, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, suds

I'm trying to take the first step in creating a SOAP client with SUDS, Python, and no success.

The WSDL is here: https://login.keyinvoice.com/API3_ws.php?wsdl

The code:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor

imp = Import("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", location="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")
    
imp.filter.add("http://login.keyinvoice.com/soap/KI_API3")
client = Client("https://login.keyinvoice.com/API3_ws.php?wsdl", doctor=ImportDoctor(imp))
```

The error:

```
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(Array, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'
```

I've tried, with no success:

- "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" as argument in the Import class
- [Type not found: '(schema, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721639/type-not-found-schema-http-www-w3-org-2001-xmlschema)
- https://github.com/unomena/suds/issues/2
- Zeep witch also doesn't work completely (it doesn't build the "authenticate" method).

Then I tried a Node lib, and it simply works, but I can't use it.

Is it the WSDL that is broken? Is it bad parameters to ImportDoctor? SUDS bug?

(Python 3.8.2, suds-community==0.8.5)

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the WSDL has 2 different ways of referring Arrays. One is xsd:array and the other is SOAP-ENC:Array. 

The xsd is defined as xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema and SOAP-ENC as xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the WSDL has 2 different ways of referring Arrays. One is xsd:array and the other is SOAP-ENC:Array.

The xsd is defined as xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" and SOAP-ENC as xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/". I do find the array in the last one and not on the first one but I'm not a expert on SOAP.

So replacing every occurrence of xsd:Array by SOAP-ENC:Array solves it in a way.. I still don't know what is wrong: the WSDL or SUDS library.